# Run a query on Parent to show records of only one child table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've 3 tables, viz A, B & c.

B & C has forign key of A.

Now I want to run a query on A, in such a way, that only records of B are returned.

That is, I want to exclude all the results of C and show only results of B, when a query is executed on all the records of A.

Hope, I've the question makes sense.

Comment: Just put the attributes you want to see in the select. For example, `SELECT B.foo, B.bar FROM A JOIN B ON B.A_id=A.id JOIN C ON C.A_id=A.id WHERE...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return all records of A and any matching records from B then something a left outer join is appropriate:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM a, b
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

This will return each record from `A` and populate values from `B` where there is a match.  This will also return multiple rows for records that occur in `A` if there are multiple rows in `B` that match.

Just because there is a foreign key in `C` that references something in table `A`, it won't be returned unless you use it in your query.

If you just want to return all records from `B` when the foreign key appears in `A` then maybe you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM B
WHERE B.id in (SELECT id FROM A)
AND B.id not in (SELECT id FROM C)
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM B 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM A JOIN B on A.id = B.id)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM C JOIN B on C.id = B.id)
```

All these assume that `id` is the key which is common.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select a.*
from a
where exists (select 1 from b where b.aid = a.aid) and
      not exists (select 1 from c where c.aid = c.aid);
```